# Add rows and populate another table (pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Two Questions:
SQL SERVER 2012 
I have a table `A (P_ID IDENTITY INT, P_Name CHAR(2), Cust_ID INT)`

```
P_ID      P_Name   Cust_ID
547       08        1
147       2B        1
21        K4        2
```

I want to replicate the rows by creating auto generated new P_ID and new P_Name in #Temp Table. Inserting new row is automatically generating P_ID.

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM TableA
INSERT INTO #Temp (P_Name, Cust_ID)
SELECT  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 0, 3), Cust_ID FROM TableA
```

But I want to make sure that the new `P_Name` is Unique. How can I populate only unique `P_Names`?

Also I Have

```
TableB (P_ID, P_Name, Cust_ID, New_P_ID, New_P_Name)
```

How do I populate `TableB` with all records and new_P_ID and new_P_Name Values from temp table ?

Comment: P_Name is only two characters . . . doesn't give you very many unique combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to create a function I think you need to use a cursor based solution.

I would create TableB first and then copy values from TableB to your temp table if needed. This, or you would need to add the primary key from TableA to your temp table in order to map it correctly when inserting the rows in TableB later.

The following code can be used to insert into TableB, you need to add logic for New_P_ID though:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT P_ID, P_Name, cust_id FROM TableA
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @name nchar(2)
DECLARE @cust_id int

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @name, @cust_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    Select @id, @name, @cust_id

    -- Get a unique name, this will hang if all 
    -- names are taken...
    DECLARE @newName nchar(2)
    DECLARE @notUnique bit = 1
    WHILE (@notUnique = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @newName = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID()) , '-', ''), 0, 3)
        SELECT @notUnique = COUNT(*) FROM TableB where New_P_Name = @newName
    END

    -- TODO: Generate the New_P_ID here...
    DECLARE @new_p_id int = 42;

    INSERT INTO TableB(P_ID, P_Name, cust_id, New_P_ID, New_P_Name)
    VALUES (@id, @name, @cust_id, @new_p_id, @newName)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @name, @cust_id
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```